# When reviewing answers: Show Tags of the question at a more visible place

Tags: feature-request, tags, review

When I review answers, I would like to check the answer for the validity of the context.
In short: Comparison with the question's tags.

(At least on my screen) The circumstance that the tags are placed below the question forces me to scroll down on each review procedure.

What about placing the tags **between** the answer to be reviewed and the original question?

---

EDIT:
In parallel to this proposal, I created a UserScript for personal use.
I reworked the samples and code snippets in this post in order to show how it looks now.

I made myself a little UserScript in order to try out what I am proposing:

```
// ==UserScript==
//
// @name           SO-Proposal: Move tags in review mode
// @description    Makes question's tags more visible when reviewing answers on small screens
// @namespace      http://nippey.dornuweb.de/
// @author         Nippey
// @version        0.1
//
// @include        http://stackoverflow.com/review/*
//
// ==/UserScript==

$(document).bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(event) {
    //If the review processes an answer and the taglist is already added to the DOM
    if ( $(".reviewable-answer").length > 0 && $(".post-taglist").length > 0) {
        //Unbind insert-event before inserting
        $(this).unbind(event);
        //And put the taglist below the 'answer' heading
        $(".reviewable-answer").prepend( 
            $(".post-taglist").clone().css("margin","0px")
                .prepend("<h4 style='display:inline;padding: 0px 10px'>Question's Tags: </h4>")
        );
    }
});
```

---

For the convenience - **Original**:

> [image: Original state]

**Preview**:

> [image: Preview]

Comment: Great post. And I very much agree. +1.

Comment: Added the UserScript that I am using myself.